# Apache cordova android build error

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an apache cordova app. Suddenly I am not able to build the app successfully. I've been testing it for three days in iOs, so I can not remember what could be the cause of this error (iOS platform is compiling well). Please help, I'm lost here. Thanks in advance

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/darkland/Development/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/darkland/Development/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/darkland/Development/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/darkland/Development/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:284: null returned: 1

Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/darkland/NetBeansProjects/Palmfest/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/darkland/NetBeansProjects/Palmfest/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Comment: Hi, find myself the solution. I backed up the files inside the platforms/android folder, then removed the Android platform, added again the android platform and then I've been able to buid successfully again the app